# Properly handle Realm object deletion

Tags: ios, swift, database, realm

I have a `Roof` object in a Realm DB, and I use it to show some data on the screen. After the user logs out, I delete the `Roof` object and then update the screen. Inside this update method the app crashes with the message: "Object has been deleted or invalidated."

Should the object become invalidated, or is this not supposed to do? Should I just check in the `update` method if the roof is invalidated, or is there a better way to handle a non-existent object?

Here is the basic code that I use:

```
class Roof: Object {
  dynamic var info: String?
}

let roof = Roof()

let realm = try! Realm()
try! realm.write {
  realm.add(roof)
}
try! realm.write {
  realm.delete(roof)
}
```

Comment: I do delete all my info when user log out, you should have other code that depends on that value, and is still referencing it, make sure to make everything related to user nil o deleted to start fresh.

Comment: Are you using the `roof` object any time after you delete it? Are you storing it on a property somewhere? It's not clear in your code sample how your view uses `roof`.

Comment: yeah, im using it as a property on some of the screens.

Answer (score 0):

Following my understand, this is the basic flow: RealmDB -> Container -> View.
When your container (may be an array) holds references to the objects in the DB, but if one was deleted before, then when you update the View, it can take `nothing`. Because your container is older than the DB.
My answer is query again (update the container), then update your view.

Answer (score 0):

When you delete object from Realm all its instances become invalid and you can't use it anymore. You can check if the object has been invalidate with [`isInvalidated`](https://realm.io/docs/swift/2.8.3/api/Classes/Object.html#/s:vC10RealmSwift6Object13isInvalidatedSb) property.